# how to find out type of delimitation of csv file in java

Tags: java, swing, validation, csv

I am trying to validate the type of files chosen from `JFilechooser` in a Java Swing application. I need to check the type of delimitation in a CSV file as only "comma" delimited CSV files are allowed. I am new to Java. Please help me to achieve the desired functionality. The part of code that I am currently working on is:

```java
ActionListener FileValidationListener = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String s  = so.getText();  // so is the JTextfield used with JFilechooser
        String t1 = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("."),s.length());

        if((!t1.equals(".xlsx")))
        {
            if(!t1.equals(".csv"))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter valid source file");
            }
        }
     }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.  By definition CSV files are pour text so the file itself gives no meta data about what delimiter is being used.

You could guess based on counting the number of times common delimiters occur in the file.

However a much better solution would be to give the user the option to tell you what delimiter they have used in the file.

Comment: please add some code to check if the csv file selected is comma delimited or anyother delimiter like semicolon is used

Comment: I have no such code.  I would never try to examine the file to figure out what the delimiter is; the margin of error is too great in my opinion, I would ask the user to tell me what they think the delimiter is on the file open dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no format CSV file formal spec. But there are some [expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Specification) for such kind of files. The main of them are

> 2. consists of records (typically one record per line),

and

> 3. where every record has the same sequence of fields.

So, for checking selected file you can load it line-by-line (records-by-records) and calc about of commas in the each read line. If the amount of commas in all lines are the same you can suppose you have a valid CSV file.

Another more general approach is trying to detect delimiter by yourself this way:

- read file line-by-line
- for each line create a map there keys are assumed field delimiter (any unique char in the line) and value is an amount of fields in this line if key value is delimiter
- you should have one map for current processed line and one map for all previous lines
- subtract map for the current line from map for the all lines
- do this analyse while you map for all lines isn't empty or till the end of the file
- if your all-line-map is empty the file isn't valid CSV file as there are no delimiters which split file lines on fields as fulfil the assumption #3
- **if you map has only 1 key-value pair the file fulfil the assumption #3 and key in the pair is your delimiter (e.g. comma) and value is amount fields in each file line**
- if there are more than 1 pairs CSV file isn't valid and the assumption #3 is fulfiled more than for 1 delimiter

Comment: please provide some sample code to achieve this functionality